# Free whole list and set head to NULL

Tags: c, list

Here's the task. It is given a linked list, free all the memory and set head to `NULL`.

This is my function:

```
void free_list(struct Node *node)
{
    while (node)
    {
        free(node);
        node=node->next;
    }
}
```

It outputs no error, just wont do anything. And another thing, how to check if the memory was freed ?

Comment: You free the node, then you try to access it again. This is illegal.

Comment: You have to make a temporary variable to store `node->next` then free the actual node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints at what's going wrong rather than sample code since this is homework...

1. You can't reliably access `node` after freeing it.  Store the value of `node->next` before freeing.
2. You're passing the `Node` pointer by value.  If you want to `NULL` the caller's pointer, use a pointer to a pointer instead.

There is no portable way to check the memory was freed, but you could investigate tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if you want to check that no memory has been leaked when your program exits.

Note that you can't check the contents of memory locations to reassure yourself that the memory has been freed.  Calling `free` merely passes ownership of the memory back to the system; it may get reallocated (and its values updated) at any point in future.

Comment: Got an aux variable and freed the space. For the 2nd thing (nulling the head), can I call the function free_list(p) and then do head=NULL ? p is assigned with head earlier before the function call.

Comment: @abyssal The best thing to do is to change `free_list` to take a pointer to a pointer to a `Node` (i.e. `struct Node** node`).  You can then set the caller's pointer to NULL at the end of your function using `*node = NULL`.  (Callers will have to change the way they call `free_list` too, passing the address of their list)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should get the next node before freeing the current one
2. If you want to assign to the head, you need to pass its address to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
void free_list(struct Node **head)
{
    struct node *nnode, *cnode;
    cnode = *head;

    while (cnode)
    {
        nnode = cnode->next;
        free(cnode);
        cnode = nnode;
    }

    *head = NULL;
}
```

call it like this..,,

`free_list(&head);`

**EDIT:**

- You are accessing the same node `node=node->next;` after freeing it, You must have to store next pointer before freeing the node.

Comment: Your code is correct but providing the OP with a complete answer to his homework without any explanation of what you've changed or why isn't going to help him learn about C programming